# Select statement is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

after i select from the db, i keep getting 0 when it's actually 1

Code:

```
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo $username;
    $sql = "SELECT activated FROM members WHERE username = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($emailactivated);
        $stmt -> close();
    echo $emailactivated;
```

Echo says 0.. it should be 1, and note : $username isn't empty

Comment: what happens when you run the query directly against the database (without using MySQLi) ? Are you getting correct results there ?

Comment: Possible silly question alert: You do have `session_start();` correct?

Comment: You mean without using prepared stmnt? well it works :D but i want to work with prepared stmnt @Fred-ii- yea lol

Comment: as @Fred-ii- mentioned, do you have session_start() at the beginning of this code ? does echo $username give you correct value for the username ?

Comment: The first line should be: `$username = $_SESSION['username'] ; `

Comment: yes.. i just said, the $username var isn't empty @Jari no?

Comment: @user2624407 I believe you need to fetch the results in order to echo, which I do not see in your posted code.

Comment: bind_result works too? :O

Comment: Thanks Fred anyway, Mchi and you were right..

Comment: @user2624407 Actually I was right as per my `fetch` [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744621/select-statement-is-not-working-properly#comment27627278_18744621), was sure it had something to do with it but you said/thought otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing `$stmt->fetch()`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($emailactivated);
    $stmt->fetch();  //right here
    $stmt -> close();
```